# How to Nest a Loop so the Entire Thing Repeats 100X

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, linear-regression, nested-loops

I have a loop that I am trying to create another loop around, but I'm not sure what the syntax should be. Here is my code:

```
for (?)
    for i=1:6
        r(i)=normrnd(0,0.1*sy);
        y_new=A+B*x+r;
    end
    % estimate new A and B
    [mm,nn]=size(x); DoF=mm-2;
    x_mean=mean(x);
    y_mean=mean(y_new);
    xp=(x-x_mean);
    yp=(y_new-y_mean);
    num=sum(xp.*yp);
    dem=sum(xp.*xp);
    B_new=num/dem;
    A_new=y_mean-B_new*x_mean;
end
```

I'm not sure what to put in the for loop to make it repeat 100X. I assume I need "for i=1:100" but then I'm not sure where in the loop to put set my x(i) to get the intended result. I'm not even sure if I nested the first loop in there correctly. I am trying to create a set of 6 new y values using normrnd and then run a linear regression to generate a new A and B (slope and intercept), and then I want to repeat that entire process 100X.

Comment: have you tried anything? Yes, of course, the only thing you need to do is the same thing you arlready did, but with a different loop variable than `i`.

Comment: Note that you're not storing results even from your existing 6-iteration loop, at the end of this (nested or not) you will be left with the last value. There are lots of questions on here already which can answer how to store loop outputs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason not to vectorize your `normrnd()` calls, you only need one level of `for`s:

```
%sy,A,B,x initialized elsewhere
for i=1:100
    r=normrnd(0,0.1*sy,[6 1]);
    y_new=A+B*x+r;
    clear r;

    % estimate new A and B
    [mm,nn]=size(x);
    DoF=mm-2;
    x_mean=mean(x);
    y_mean=mean(y_new);
    xp=(x-x_mean);
    yp=(y_new-y_mean);
    num=sum(xp.*yp);
    dem=sum(xp.*xp);
    B_new=num/dem;
    A_new=y_mean-B_new*x_mean;
    %set B=B_new and A=A_new for the next iteration maybe?
end
clear i;
```